# FileZilla connections tab on Ubuntu

Tags: sftp, filezilla

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus), and I'd like to use FileZilla as my SFTP client. But I need to use two or more connections at the same time very regularly, and I can't seem to find connection tab anywhere.

This might be case of me being blind, but I can't find a tab of open connections and every time I try to connect, FileZilla` asks if I want to disconnect the previous session. I just can't find it anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you try to connect on a tab that is already connected,

FileZilla should ask you if you want to abort current connection or establish a new one in a new tab.

There are two options to open new tab explicitly

1. File > New Tab
2. [Keyboard shortcut:](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Keyboard_shortcuts) `CTRL(control) + T`

Tested on Ubuntu 17.

Other OS: This also works on Windows, on Mac it may be `Cmd ⌘ + T`